# How to split the csv data with a column of JSON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data (.csv) looks like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
XXX, BBB, "[{\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}, {\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}]", DDD, EEE, GGG
XXX, BBB, "[{\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}]", DDD, , GGG
```

When I use pd.read_csv(), the result would be:

[result from my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdOI3.png)

I want the table to be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | BBB | [{"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX",col33:1}, {"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX","col33":1}] | DDD | EEE | GGG |
| XXX | BBB | [{"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX",col33:1}] | DDD |  | GGG |

and column 3 is in the list of dictionaries format.

Comment: "I want the table would be:" - okay, so **what happens** when you use the normal tools for reading a CSV file into Pandas? **How is that different** from what you want? Please read [ask] and make sure to **describe a problem** and **ask a question**.

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry for the mistake. I edited the question and added the result from what I tried. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @mozway I don't think the problem is about converting the JSON-formatted strings into objects within the Dataframe. It looks like there is a problem with reading the data, because the commas within the JSON are being treated as CSV separators. I assume there is some problem with configuring the `.load_csv` call.

Comment: @Karl you might be correct, it wasn't clear to me when I read it

Comment: Well, it might not yet have been edited at that point, I didn't check the timestamps carefully ;)

Comment: @Karl I also surely have biases, many questions could be interpreted in several ways

Comment: @JSM CSV files don't use \ for escape sequences. Double quotes inside a quoted field are simply doubled. Any CSV parser would simply crash when it encountered `"[{\"` without a following comma, or treat `"[{\"col31\":\"XXX\"` as a single string value. CSV is a *simple* format and knows nothing about JSON

Comment: @Panagiotis the issue with CSV is that there is unfortunately not a unique standard, but many variants, this is a mess ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have issues with quoting/escaping, this can be handled from scratch by pandas but you have to pass the correct parameters to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) as the default parameters won't work for you:

- `sep=','` to specify the field separator (default)
- `quotechar='"'` to indicate that `"` are quotes (default)
- **`escapechar='\\'` to indicate that `\` is escaping some of the `"`**
- **`skipinitialspace=True` to ignore the spaces after the `,` delimiters**

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"',
                 escapechar='\\', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2                                                                                col3 col4 col5 col6
0  XXX  BBB  [{"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX","col33":1}, {"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX","col33":1}]  DDD  EEE  GGG
1  XXX  BBB                                           [{"col31":"XXX","col32":"XXX","col33":1}]  DDD  NaN  GGG
```

Note that this will import the "list of dictionaries" as strings, if you need python objects, you can further use:

```
import ast

df['col3'] = df['col3'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: It should be stressed that the important part is `escapechar='\\'.`.

Comment: @Panagiotis and `skipinitialspace=True` that would fail without it as the spaces are outside of the quoted part. That's why I highlighted which are the default parameters, but I can try to highlight it even more ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Raw data
data = """
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
XXX, BBB, "[{\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}, {\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}]", DDD, EEE, GGG
XXX, BBB, "[{\"col31\":\"XXX\",\"col32\":\"XXX\",\"col33\":1}]", DDD, , GGG
"""

def split_outside_brackets(line):
    """Split a string by commas that are outside of square brackets."""
    parts = []
    start = 0
    bracket_depth = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(line):
        if char == '[':
            bracket_depth += 1
        elif char == ']':
            bracket_depth -= 1
        elif char == ',' and bracket_depth == 0:
            parts.append(line[start:i].strip())
            start = i + 1
    parts.append(line[start:].strip())
    return parts

# Split the data into lines
lines = data.strip().split('\n')

# Process each line
processed_lines = [split_outside_brackets(line) for line in lines]

# Convert to a DataFrame
df_result = pd.DataFrame(processed_lines[1:], columns=processed_lines[0])

# Correct the single quotes around col33 and decode the JSON
df_result['col3'] = df_result['col3'].str[1:-1].apply(json.loads)

df_result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).